# Elasticsearch doesn't cache query with rounded date

Tags: elasticsearch, caching

I'm using this Elasticsearch query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"term": {"address.country.keyword": "Germany"}},
            {"term": {"address.city.keyword": "Berlin"}},
            {"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": "now-3d/h"}}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

AFAICT this should qualify the query for caching, at least based on these resources:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/tune-for-search-speed.html#_search_rounded_dates
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/common-options.html#date-math
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html

However, according to the `/_stats/request_cache` endpoint caching is not involved - `hit_count` stays the same. If I remove the range clause, it works. Also if I change the time specification to `now/h`, it also works. Am I missing something?

Elasticsearch's version is 6.2.3.

Comment: I tried your exact same case above and the first time I get a miss, but then I get hits every time, with the same query

Comment: Did you try with the exact version? I tried it again and now it gets really weird - not only does it work only when I specify `now` only, but it works only with `h` rounding. When I specify whatever else (`d`, `M`, ...) it doesn't work... Do you have any clues what could I try to debug this?

Comment: @Val Also, I now tried to enforce caching using `request_cache=true` but still, it won't cache the query...

Comment: Indeed, I haven't tried on 6.2.3, but on 7.9.1... I'll spin up a cluster with that version and check again